# MYSQL Min Max Historic Values

Tags: sql, mysql, max, window-functions, min

I have a MYSQL table with this format:

```
Insurance Date Value
A 2020-01-01 2
A 2020-02-01 5
A 2020-03-01 4
A 2020-04-01 6
A 2020-05-01 8
A 2020-06-01 1
A 2020-07-01 3
A 2020-08-01 7
A 2020-09-01 9
A 2020-10-01 3
A 2020-11-01 5
A 2020-12-01 6
B 2020-01-01 5
...
```

I want SELECT Min and Max from this way (historic value)

```
in date 2020-01-01 Min 2 Max 2
in date 2020-02-01 Min 2 Max 5
in date 2020-03-01 Min 2 Max 5
in date 2020-04-01 Min 2 Max 6
In date 2020-05-01 Min 2 Max 8
In date 2020-06-01 Min 1 Max 8
In date 2020-07-01 Min 1 Max 8
In date 2020-08-01 Min 1 Max 8
In date 2020-09-01 Min 1 Max 9
In date 2020-10-01 Min 1 Max 9
In date 2020-11-01 Min 1 Max 9
In date 2020-12-01 Min 1 Max 9
```

T try to fin the solution, but only I get min and max value from a between dates, but not month to month with reference at last months.

Can you help me? THANKS

Comment: It's not clear how your desired result relates to the data. Why is the max for `2020-01-01` only 2, when your data has the row `B 2020-01-01 5`

Comment: If you can get between dates, why not between day 1 and day 31 or how ever many days that month has?  Then you can select that value to have the reference for that month (to use in the next perhaps?)

Comment: @easleyfixed Their data doesn't have any dates other that 1 of each month.

Comment: @Barmar the 5 is for B, so min/max appear to be running values for each A/B value.  odd that A/B aren't in the output, though, maybe that is what in/In are supposed to be?

Comment: Are you using MySQL 8.x? You should be able to do running min/max with window functions.

Comment: Are you using MySQL 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *seem* to be looking for a window min/max over all preceding rows of the same insurance. You can use window functions (available in MySQL 8.0):

```
select t.*,
    min(val) over(partition by insurance order by dt) min_val_so_far,
    max(val) over(partition by insurance order by dt) max_val_so_far
from mytable t
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GCnP3W9r)**:

| insurance | dt | val | min_val_so_far | max_val_so_far |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2020-01-01 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| A | 2020-02-01 | 5 | 2 | 5 |
| A | 2020-03-01 | 4 | 2 | 5 |
| A | 2020-04-01 | 6 | 2 | 6 |
| A | 2020-05-01 | 8 | 2 | 8 |
| A | 2020-06-01 | 1 | 1 | 8 |
| A | 2020-07-01 | 3 | 1 | 8 |
| A | 2020-08-01 | 7 | 1 | 8 |
| A | 2020-09-01 | 9 | 1 | 9 |
| A | 2020-10-01 | 3 | 1 | 9 |
| A | 2020-11-01 | 5 | 1 | 9 |
| A | 2020-12-01 | 6 | 1 | 9 |

Comment: It's perfect! Is just that I need it. THANKS SO MUCH.

Answer (score 0):

Try the follow query to get min and max value of a date from table: -

```
SELECT DISTINCT date, MAX(value) AS max_value, MIN(value) as min_value
FROM table_name group by data;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the GMB answer is just that I need it.